# Web Config problem in asp.net. i am using vs 2010. my web.config is given below

Tags: c#

```
 <?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
    <appSettings>
        <add key="ConnectionInfo" value="server=127.0.1.1;database=Info_mgmt;Integrated Security=SSPI"/>
    </appSettings>
    <connectionStrings>
        <add name="Info_mgmtConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=daffodils\sqlexpress;Initial Catalog=Info_mgmt;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
    </connectionStrings>
    <system.web>
        <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0">
        </compilation>
        <!--
            The <authentication> section enables configuration 
            of the security authentication mode used by 
            ASP.NET to identify an incoming user. 
        -->
        <authentication mode="Windows"/>
        <!--
            The <customErrors> section enables configuration 
            of what to do if/when an unhandled error occurs 
            during the execution of a request. Specifically, 
            it enables developers to configure html error pages 
            to be displayed in place of a error stack trace.

        <customErrors mode="RemoteOnly" defaultRedirect="GenericErrorPage.htm">
            <error statusCode="403" redirect="NoAccess.htm" />
            <error statusCode="404" redirect="FileNotFound.htm" />
        </customErrors>
        -->
        <pages controlRenderingCompatibilityVersion="3.5" clientIDMode="AutoID"/></system.web>
    <!-- 
        The system.webServer section is required for running ASP.NET AJAX under Internet
        Information Services 7.0.  It is not necessary for previous version of IIS.
    -->
</configuration>
```

Error:

Configuration Error
Description: An error occurred during the processing of a configuration file required to service this request. Please review the specific error details below and modify your configuration file appropriately.

Parser Error Message: Unrecognized attribute 'targetFramework'. Note that attribute names are case-sensitive.

Source Error:

Line 7:     
Line 8:     
Line 9:         
Line 10:        
Line 11:

Source File: D:\Infopass\Infopass-Web\Infopass-Web\web.config    Line: 9

Comment: Please show the part of the configuration file that causes the error. There is no targetFramework attribute in the code shown.

Comment: I am running in Visual Studio ..

Comment: <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0"> here error is coming

Comment: Please see the update to my answer below.  Hope that helps.

Answer (score 4):

The targetFramework attribute is specified on the <compilation> element under <system.web>.  I have seen that error message when running sites in IIS 7.5 using ASP.NET 2.0 instead of ASP.NET 4.0.  If this site is in IIS, then check the Application Pool the site is running under to make sure the Application Pool is using the .NET 4.0 Framework (instead of .NET 2.0 Framework).

Similarly, if you are attempting to run the site from the default web server in Visual Studio and you are seeing this error, you'll want to make sure the Target Framework for the project is set to .NET Framework 4.0 (under Properties > Build > Target Framework).

Comment: I can provide more detail as to what to look for, but can you update the question with the web server you are using? IIS6, IIS7, the built in ASP.NET web server?

Answer (score 1):

You need to set your application to use .Net 4.0 in IIS.